# How to find/define JMX key for ActiveMQ Artemis monitoring

Tags: monitoring, jmx, zabbix, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to setup monitoring of ActiveMQ Artemis with Zabbix. My intention is to monitor the availability of Artemis and also monitor the size and number of messages accumulating in queues, and setup alerts.

I enabled JMX on Artemis as the documents in struct, and I built the JMX example. From what I can tell, this only involves adding the following lines to these two files in the broker:

management.xml

```
<connector connector-port="1099" connector-host="192.168.56.101" />
```

Opened the port:
sudo ufw allow 1099

broker.xml

```
<jmx-management-enabled>true</jmx-management-enabled>
```

So I think JMX is enabled, although I haven't managed to confirm this.

In Zabbix I added the "host" (a system to monitor), but the next step is creating an "item" (a thing on the system). To do this I need a JMX key, something similar to jmx["java.lang:type=Memory","HeapMemoryUsage.used"]. (I tried this one but I don't get any data back) This defines the MBean to call.

So where can I find the keys for the available things to monitor on Artemis? Or have I screwed something up here and am not looking for the right thing?

In the example there is a JMWExample.java program. It connects to Artemis, publishes a message, uses JMX to count the messages, then removes the message -- but I don't see any keys to MBeans.

Also, in the admin console for Artemis there is a JMX tab, which lists what I think is all the available *things to monitor.* For example, I have a queue called "test.queue". Under the JMX tab I find:

```
org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="test.topic",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="multicast",queue="test.queue"
```

And there are numerous methods listed, including countMessages(). Have I answered my own question here? Is this what I'm looking for?

If so, how does it fit into this key format, jmx[object_name,attribute_name]

{EDIT}

I'm looking at the JMX tab on the console. If I understand correctly, the key should have a format like this: jmx[object_name,attribute_name]

So I see the the object name under the JMX tab for one of my test queues is: org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="test.topic",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="multicast",queue="test.queue"

And it has an attribute of: MessageCount

So I treid this, which doesn't work. I also tried replacing 0.0.0.0 with the IP address.

jmx[org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker="0.0.0.0",component=addresses,address="test.topic",subcomponent=queues,routing-type="multicast",queue="test.queue",MessageCount]

Comment: Can you connect to your ActiveMQ Artemis instance using [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) ?

Comment: It looks like you're not properly formatting the object name. I updated my comment with additional information that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value for `<jmx-management-enabled>` is `true` so you don't *need* to explicitly configure that.

You can confirm that JMX is enabled by connecting to the broker using a tool like JConsole or JVisualVM which ship with the JVM. Ideally you would do this locally to avoid any network configuration issues.

The broker exposes lots of different MBeans for managing all parts of the broker. Here are the different "control" objects with their default MBean object naming *pattern*:

- [`ActiveMQServerControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ActiveMQServerControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>`
- [`AddressControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/AddressControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=addresses,address=<addressName>`
- [`QueueControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=addresses,address=<addressName>,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=<routingType>,queue=<queueName>`
- [`DivertControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/DivertControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=addresses,address=<addressName>,subcomponent=diverts,divert=<divertName>`
- [`ClusterConnectionControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/ClusterConnectionControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=cluster-connections,name=<clusterConnectionName>`
- [`AcceptorControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/AcceptorControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=acceptors,name=<acceptorName>`
- [`BroadcastGroupControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/BroadcastGroupControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=broadcast-groups,name=<broadcastGroupName>`
- [`BridgeControl`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/BridgeControl.html): `<domain>:broker=<brokerName>,component=bridges,name=<bridgeName>`

The "key" that you use will depend on the name of the attribute from the control that you want to inspect. That name will correspond to the "getter" of the attribute. You can see all the names of all the getters in the linked JavaDoc. For example, if you want to get the number of messages from a queue you'd use the key `MessageCount` since the getter is named [`getMessageCount()`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/javadocs/javadoc-latest/org/apache/activemq/artemis/api/core/management/QueueControl.html#getMessageCount--).

The *domain* by default is `org.apache.activemq.artemis` and the default broker *name* is `localhost` so if you didn't explicitly configure either of these and you wanted to get the message count of the anycast queue "myQueue" on the address "myAddress" you would use something *like* this:

```
jmx["org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"localhost\",component=addresses,address=\"myAddress\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=\"myQueue\"",MessageCount]
```

This formatting is based on [this Zabbix block post](https://blog.zabbix.com/putting-dots-on-jmx-monitoring/1673/) which is also discussed on [this Zabbix forum thread](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-troubleshooting-and-problems/28967-format-of-jmx-keys-that-contain-double-quotes).

To be clear, the [`JMXExample` you cited](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/examples/features/standard/jmx/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/JMXExample.java#L78) uses a handy helper method named `getQueueObjectName` to construct the MBean's object name.

If you need to quickly get a broker up and running which supports remote JMX clients do the following:

- Open the directory `examples/features/standard/jmx` in a terminal.
- Run the example using `mvn clean verify`.
- This will create a full broker instance in `target/server0` which you can use as a template to configure your own. It includes modifications to `broker.xml`, `management.xml`, and `artemis.profile` (to set the `java.rmi.server.hostname` system property).

If you start this broker instance manually you can connect to it with JConsole or JVisualVM using `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi`.

Comment: Hi Justin. I switched management.xml to use <connector connector-port="1099" connector-host="localhost"/> and tried to connect with jconsole running on the same machine. I tried using the connection "localhost:1099" and "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi" to connect using Remote Process, but both failed. I can connect using jconsole's local process connection, but that looks like it's missing Artemis MBeans. Does this mean JMX isn't enabled properly?

Comment: Sounds like something isn't configured correctly. I updated my answer to provide additional guidance. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Justin. Yes. I just sorted it out. I was missing the system property in the artemis.profile, java.rmi.server.hostname. To enable JMX from another server, should java.rmi.server.hostname be set to the Artemis server's IP/host and in management.xml set <connector connector-port="1099" connector-host="[monitoring server]" /> to use the external JConsole/JVisualVM/Zabbix monitoring server?

Comment: Both `java.rmi.server.hostname` and `connector-host` should be set to the same value.

Comment: Hi Justin. Could you add an example key to your answer? jmx[object_name,attribute_name]

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!