# Report ActiveMQ Artemis metrics using Telegraf jolokia2_agent plugin

Tags: activemq-artemis, telegraf, jolokia

So we recently migrated from ActiveMQ "Classic" to ActiveMQ Artemis and it seems like we are unable to get our Telegraf configuration right for `inputs.jolokia2_agent`.

```
[[inputs.jolokia2_agent]]
  urls = [ "http://<artemis-live-instance>:8161/console/jolokia/", "http://<artemis-backup-instance>:8161/console/jolokia/" ]
  username = "<user>"
  password = "<password>"

  [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
    name  = "artemis"
    mbean = "org.apache.activemq.artemis:type=Broker,brokerName=*,destinationType=*,destinationName=<destination-root>.*"
    paths = [ "AverageEnqueueTime", "AverageMessageSize", "BlockedSends", "ConsumerCount", "DequeueCount", "DispatchCount", "EnqueueCount", "ExpiredCount", "ForwardCount", "InFlightCount", "MaxEnqueueTime", "MemoryPercentUsage", "MemoryUsageByteCount", "MinEnqueueTime", "ProducerCount", "QueueSize", "StoreMessageSize" ]
    tag_keys = [ "destinationName", "destinationType" ]

  [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
    name  = "artemis"
    mbean = "org.apache.activemq.artemis:type=Broker,brokerName=*,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=ActiveMQ.DLQ"
    paths = [ "AverageEnqueueTime", "AverageMessageSize", "BlockedSends", "ConsumerCount", "DequeueCount", "DispatchCount", "EnqueueCount", "ExpiredCount", "ForwardCount", "InFlightCount", "MaxEnqueueTime", "MemoryPercentUsage", "MemoryUsageByteCount", "MinEnqueueTime", "ProducerCount", "QueueSize", "StoreMessageSize" ]
    tag_keys = [ "destinationName", "destinationType" ]
```

We are heavily using Grafana so it's pretty important to get metrics for ActiveMQ Artemis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any examples from Telegraf documentation but I was able to figure it out using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64863179/9056976).

```
[[inputs.jolokia2_agent]]
  urls = [ "http://<artemis-live-instance>:8161/console/jolokia/", "http://<artemis-backup-instance>:8161/console/jolokia/" ]
  username = "<user>"
  password = "<password>"
  
  [[inputs.jolokia2_agent.metric]]
    name  = "artemis"
    mbean = "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"*\",component=addresses,address=\"<queue-prefix>.*\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"anycast\",queue=\"<queue-prefix>.*\""
    tag_keys = ["queue", "subcomponent"]
```

Another problem occured - as you can see I've converted queue names into tags but they are stored with double quotes around them. For example: "example.queue.name" should be just example.queue.name (without double quotes).

As double quotes are not trimmed by default I had to use a bit of a workaround.

```
[[processors.strings]]
  namepass = ["artemis"]

  [[processors.strings.trim]]
    tag = "queue"
    cutset = '"'
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend considering a [metrics plugin](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html#metrics). One already exists for [Prometheus](https://github.com/rh-messaging/artemis-prometheus-metrics-plugin). I think one for Telegraf/Influx would be even easier to implement.